# Carousel indicators not displaying or moving onto next image in slide

Tags: html, carousel

As Select my indicators to move onto the next section of the slide
show, upon clicking it does not work. is there any reason to why this 
is not working

```
<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class ="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="carousel-inner active">
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src ="img/background.png">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src ="img/background2.png">
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a> 

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly you mean by "not working". See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is, just add some color on active slide's indicator, I have used your code, and aaded a single line in css, and you can see the result.

```css
body {background: #333 !important;}
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom: -50px !important;
}
.carousel-indicators li.active {background: red;}
.carousel-item {color: white; font-size: 80px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.4.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class ="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="carousel-inner active">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
           1
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            222
        </div>
<div class="carousel-item">
           3333
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a> 

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```